# php mysql - search like - variable

Tags: php

I have a form where a user can type in the firstname to search, my query is not returning the correct results, what am I doing wrong?

```
$sfn = $_POST["Text1"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ex_usrs WHERE firstname LIKE '$sfn'";
...
```

Comment: You really should escape the stuff you put in a query... Security, anyone?

Comment: I will start with that, thank you, it's for an internal site, but still, it has to be done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query will only return rows where `firstname` is *equal to* `$_POST["Text1"]`.  When you use `LIKE` you can use a wildcard (`%`) to represent any number of characters.

- This will find rows where `firstname` *starts with*  `$_POST["Text1"]`.

  ```
  SELECT * FROM ex_usrs WHERE firstname LIKE '$sfn%'
  ```
- This will find rows where `firstname` *ends with*  `$_POST["Text1"]`.

  ```
  SELECT * FROM ex_usrs WHERE firstname LIKE '%$sfn'
  ```
- This will find rows where `firstname` *contains*  `$_POST["Text1"]`.

  ```
  SELECT * FROM ex_usrs WHERE firstname LIKE '%$sfn%'
  ```

Note: **Never** use variables from `$_POST` without escaping them first.  What if I searched for `"O'Neil"` (or worse `"'; DROP TABLE ex_users; -- "`)?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you should add %-signs to your keyword like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ex_usrs WHERE firstname LIKE '%$sfn%'";
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `%searchterm%` - include the `%` wildcards.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ex_usrs WHERE firstname LIKE '%$sfn%'";
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
 "SELECT * FROM ex_usrs WHERE firstname LIKE '%$sfn%'"
```